# Angular - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm not too sure how to phrase the question in a better way, but I 
need some help in understanding how to resolve this. The following is my error:

1. `TypeError: _co.create is not a function`
2. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

When I try to use `newCategory.name` in the html, it throws these errors in the console. So I think the problem lies within the HTML.

**newCategory** is defined in **CreateCategoryComponent.ts**

```
newCategory: Category;
name: string;
description: string;
```

**CategoryService.ts**

```
 //ommitted some redundant code
 baseUrl: string = "api/Category";

 createCategory(newCategory: Category) : Observable<any> {

  //Not too sure if newCategory is added correctly here
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.baseUrl+"username="+this.sessionService.getUsername()+"&password="+this.sessionService.getPassword() + newCategory).pipe (
    catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

**CreateCategory.html**

```
<td><input id="name" name="name" #name="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="newCategory.name" required="true" /></td>
```

Comment: `newCategory: Category;` this only defines newCategory to be type of Category, but it doesn't initialize values

Comment: `newCategory` is declared inside your component, but not defined

Comment: @mxr7350 yes. I missed out that. Thank you. Needed to add this.newCategory = new Category();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your HTML.

The problem is `newCategory: Category;` as values are not initialized. All you are doing here is setting newCategory to be `type of` Category.

You can initialize newCategory on the following ways:

1. Using `new` operator

```
       newCategory: Category = new Category();
```

2. I usually declare initial state in Category model file and than import it into appropriate files.

```
    export const initialState: Category = {
      name: '',
      description: ''
    };
```

3. Initialize values in the component

```
    newCategory: Category = {
      name: '',
      description: ''
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Your component has 3 attributes:

- newCategory: Category;
- name: string;
- description: string;

Then your needs set/get the attribute name, you'll use: `name`.

```html
<td><input id="name" name="name" #name="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" required="true" /></td>
```

Or you needs add `name` to your `newCategory` object:

```js
newCategory: Category = {
    name: string, 
    description: string
};
```

And use `newCategory.name` in your template:

```html
<td><input id="name" name="name" #name="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="newCategory.name" required="true" /></td>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

This occurred for me when the page was loaded before the object was returned from an async call. My solutions was an *ngIf block.

```
<div *ngIf="object"><br />
<b>{{ object.property1}}</b><br />
<i>{{ object.property2}}</i><br />
</div>
```